# RTE 438: Object Doesnt Support this property or Method - Updating existing item values based on dictionary key

Tags: excel, vba

Im at a loss on why I am getting the Run Time Error of 438 when trying to update items in a dictionary based on the key.  Please note I am still very new to using Dictionaries in VBA.  I decided to use the cell address as the key, but I think this may cause an issue later on when rows are deleted and added; I will address this later if it does cause issues. 
Back to the issue at hand:  I am receiving the Run Time Error on `allLoans(thisLoanNum) = TempVal` within the `Public Sub UpdateLoanDictionary(ByRef thisLoanNum As Range)` when ever I update one of the cells within the specified ranges.  I have placed all of the functions, class modules and subs in one code block, but if I need to split them up and label them as such I will.  I have tried looping through the keys (current setup) and not looping through the keys in the `Worksheet_Change` event, but both ways cause the same error.

**Data Set:**  These are the columns with data the code looks at
Loan Number | Customer Name | Processor | Title Company | Closing Date | Contract Price | Loan Amount | Notes

**Class Module**

```
'--Class: LoanData
Public LoanAmount As String
Public TitleCompany As String
Public Notes As String
Public closeDate As String
Public PurchasePrice As String
Public Product As String
Public LoanNumber As String
Public CustomerName As String
Public ProcessorName As String
Public Sub Populate(ByRef loanDetails As Range)
    With loanDetails
        LoanAmount = Trim(.Offset(0, 16).Value)
        closeDate = Trim(.Offset(0, 10).Value)
        Notes = Trim(.Offset(0, 19).Value)
        LoanNumber = .Offset(0, 0).Cells.Address
        Product = Trim(.Offset(0, 17).Value)
        PurchasePrice = Trim(.Offset(0, 15).Value)
        TitleCompany = Trim(.Offset(0, 4).Value)
        If CBool(InStr(1, .Offset(0, 1), " - ")) Then
            CustomerName = Trim(Split(.Offset(0, 1).Value, " - ")(0))
        Else
            CustomerName = Trim(.Offset(0, 1).Value)
        End If
        ProcessorName = Trim(.Offset(0, 2).Value)
    End With
End Sub
```

**Worksheet Change Event**

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim loanNumbers As Range
    Set loanNumbers = Sheet1.Range("LoanNums,CloseDate,ContractPrice,LoanAmnt,LoanNotes,Product")

    Dim allChangedCells As Range
    Set allChangedCells = Intersect(Target, loanNumbers)
    If Not allChangedCells Is Nothing Then
        Dim changedCell As Range
        For Each changedCell In allChangedCells
            UpdateLoanDictionary changedCell
        Next changedCell
        Dim uLoan As New LoanData
        CreateEmail uLoan.CustomerName, uLoan.TitleCompany, uLoan.closeDate, uLoan.PurchasePrice, uLoan.LoanAmount, uLoan.Product, uLoan.Notes
    End If
End Sub
```

**Standard Module named LoanDataSupport**

```
Option Explicit
Private allLoans As Dictionary
Public Sub CreateLoanDictionary(Optional ByVal forceNewDictionary As Boolean = False)
    '--- if the dictionary already exists, we don't have to recreate it
    '    unless it's forced
    If forceNewDictionary Or (allLoans Is Nothing) Then
        Set allLoans = New Dictionary
        Dim loanNums As Range
        Set loanNums = ActiveSheet.Range("LoanNums")
        Dim loannum As Range
        For Each loannum In loanNums
            UpdateLoanDictionary loannum
        Next loannum
    End If
End Sub
Public Sub UpdateLoanDictionary(ByRef thisLoanNum As Range)
    '--- just in case this Sub is called before the dictionary is created
    If allLoans Is Nothing Then CreateLoanDictionary
    'If IsEmpty(thisLoanNum.Value) Then Exit Sub

    Dim thisLoan As LoanData
    Set thisLoan = New LoanData
    thisLoan.Populate thisLoanNum

    If Not allLoans.Exists(thisLoan.LoanNumber) Then
        '--- create a new loan entry
        allLoans.Add thisLoan.LoanNumber, thisLoan
    Else
        Dim loanKey As Variant
        For Each loanKey In allLoans.Keys
            Dim TempVal As New LoanData
                allLoans(thisLoanNum) = TempVal
        Next loanKey

        '--- update the existing loan entry
        'allLoans(thisLoanNum) = thisLoan  <--This causes same error as the loop.
    End If
End Sub
Sub ShowLoans()
    If allLoans Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "There is no loan dictionary!"
    Else
        If allLoans.Count = 0 Then
            Debug.Print "There is a loan dictionary, but it's empty!"
        Else
            Debug.Print "There are " & allLoans.Count & " loans in the dictionary:"
            Dim loan As Variant
            For Each loan In allLoans.Items
                Debug.Print "Loan Number: " & loan.LoanNumber & "Notes: " & loan.Notes
            Next loan
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT**
Forgot to give credit to the fine people that helped me on Code Review with originally helping me with this code from [This Post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/233488/add-items-to-dictionary-from-another-dictionary-on-cell-value-change)

Comment: It would help to understand that these are not all located in the same module. I see 2 `Option Explicit` lines in the middle of your code and a `Worksheet_Change()` event, but it's not very clear that these are, in fact, in the proper modules - it just looks as if this was all in your class module. Quite honestly, most of this code is not needed here anyway and deflects from providing a [mre] (hence the "Minimal").

Comment: when using a variable as a key in a scripting dictionary, set it to an actual string variable first (instead of a range as you now have it) - i know it seems weird, but this happened to me once before and that solved it.

Comment: `thisLoanNum` is a `range` variable... you are passing it into a `dictionary` item if you do a `debug.print thisLoanNum` does it match an item within the existing `dictionary`?

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs I updated the code and where it is located to hopefully clear that up for you.

Comment: @braX I tried that, but unfortunately changing it to a string wont work in this case because my Class Module requires it to be a range.

Comment: Just declare another variable, and set it to the range value converted to a string. dont change the definition of the existing one.

Comment: `Dim sTemp as String: sTemp = thisLoanNum` then `allLoans(sTemp) = TempVal`

Comment: Does `allLoans(thisLoanNum.Value)` or even `allLoans(thisLoanNum.Text)` not work? Explicitly calling the properties you are wanting to use instead of implicitly using an object's default method is good coding practice. Also, did you check to ensure that `thisLoanNum` is a single cell? Because if not then you are just returning an array of values to something that is expecting a simple string.

Comment: @alowflyingpig I get the value in the cell when i run `debug.print thisLoanNum`

Comment: If your class requiresit to be a range can you simply convert it like `CStr(thisLoanNum)`

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs niether `Does allLoans(thisLoanNum.Value)` or `allLoans(thisLoanNum.Text)` work.  I have to store the items of the dictionary in an Array.  Maybe I just need to rethink not using a dictionary for this and just store the values from those ranges on a hidden sheet in the workbook then compare any changes against those cell values at least until i have had more practice with using Dictionaries on simpler projects.

Comment: Did you try my idea? After I explained it more?

Comment: @braX I did and maybe i missed something because i couldnt get that to work either :(

Comment: You couldnt define a new string variable? you couldnt set the range variable to a string? my experience is that it has to be an actual string variable to work, but you can make one easily out of the range value.

Comment: I could define the new string but then I received a 1004 error. Maybe I just need to sleep on this one and see if it clicks tomorrow.

Comment: I was able to get this to work, but not in a way that is probably the correct way, but I will deal with that later.  It did open up another issue, but I will post that separate issue if i cant figure it out.  Thanks everyone

Comment: @braX  My understanding is the class module already converts it to a string, so I think im just going to delete the dictionary part of this project and start it from scratch.

Comment: @alowflyingpig unfortunately I cannot convert it to a string. Do I just need to create a new Class Module to handle updating the Dictionary?